# Save objects into Android Realm DB on api call

Tags: android, realm

I want to store objects received from API call into realm db.

Sample Obj:

```
[
        {
            "obj_type": "ClassSession",
            "_id": "0341bd22-1182-4db3-a667-c8647012741e",
            "version": "b2",
            "createdOn": "2017-04-01 12:57:39 +0530",
            "stage": "SCHEDULED",
            "type": "Class Session",
            "scheduled_at": "2017-04-01 12:58:39 +0530"
        },
        {
            "obj_type": "Assignment",
            "_id": "CmsRsrc2",
            "version": "b3",
            "name": "Homework",
            "type": "HOMEWORK",
            "parent": {
                "type": "topic",
                "id": "parent_id1"
            },
            "resource_id": "CmsRsrc2",
            "assignmentProperty": {}
        },
        {
            "obj_type": "Task",
            "_id": "21b72bc0eb3e6d4a1c2bb332593ee19bbc527c92c9249585bed785fc6339e155",
            "version": "b0",
            "source": {
                "type": "T_PROBLEM",
                "id": "problem_id1_1"
            },
            "correctAnswer": 1
        },
        {
            "obj_type": "TaskRecord",
            "_id": "ff0748aea74431786a20629ad57676fc84eaa7396b153206540ee9eac1d9bfc8",
            "assignmentId": "CmsRsrc2",
            "version": "b0/",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "marking_scheme": {},
            "sequence": 1
        }
    ]
```

I have realm class for each obj_type but I don't know how to receive the obj from api as the response obj received from api does not belong to any realm class.

So I am looking for a way to receive the obj sent by api and save it to corresponding realm class.

Comment: Build out a model that looks for this structure, and bind it to your realm objects. Essentially an object that has pointers to your realm objects as a deserialization of your api

Comment: I can't as the response have multiple objects of different Realm classes

Comment: technically you need to parse the JSON manually, populate the lists that store the given types of objects, and then save each list into Realm.